# Jenkins JUnit retaining the results even it's already cleaned up

Tags: selenium, jenkins, junit

I have a Jenkins pipeline with 2 stages, they both clean up and count the test results using JUnit. My issue is that when I'm now running stage 2, Jenkins JUnit is still able to count the cleaned up test-output directory from Stage 1. How is that possible? I only wanted to count the test result  from stage 2.

```
           stage('1'){  
             //Insert code to delete test-output directory here
             //Insert build trigger here
                    junit '***/test-output/TEST-*.xml'

                    script {
                        AbstractTestResultAction testResultAction =  currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(AbstractTestResultAction.class)
                        if (testResultAction != null) {
                            def totalNumberOfTests = testResultAction.totalCount
                            def failedNumberOfTests = testResultAction.failCount
                            def failedDiff = testResultAction.failureDiffString
                            def skippedNumberOfTests = testResultAction.skipCount
                            def passedNumberOfTests = totalNumberOfTests - failedNumberOfTests - skippedNumberOfTests
                            emailTestReport = "Tests Report:\n Passed: ${passedNumberOfTests}; Failed: ${failedNumberOfTests} ${failedDiff}; Skipped: ${skippedNumberOfTests}  out of ${totalNumberOfTests} "
                        }
                    }

                    mail to: 'example@email.com',
                    subject: "Tests are finished: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
                    body: "Tests are finished  ${env.BUILD_URL}\n  Test Report: ${emailTestReport} "
                }

            }
        }
stage('2'){

           //Insert Code to delete test-output directory here
          //Insert build trigger here
                    junit '***/test-output/TEST-*.xml'

                    script {
                        AbstractTestResultAction testResultAction =  currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(AbstractTestResultAction.class)
                        if (testResultAction != null) {
                            def totalNumberOfTests = testResultAction.totalCount
                            def failedNumberOfTests = testResultAction.failCount
                            def failedDiff = testResultAction.failureDiffString
                            def skippedNumberOfTests = testResultAction.skipCount
                            def passedNumberOfTests = totalNumberOfTests - failedNumberOfTests - skippedNumberOfTests
                            emailTestReport = "Tests Report:\n Passed: ${passedNumberOfTests}; Failed: ${failedNumberOfTests} ${failedDiff}; Skipped: ${skippedNumberOfTests}  out of ${totalNumberOfTests} "
                        }
                    }

                    mail to: 'example@email.com',
                    subject: "Tests are finished: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
                    body: "Tests are finished  ${env.BUILD_URL}\n  Test Report: ${emailTestReport} "
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

By calling the junit(...) step the given test results get parsed and registered with the build run. To perform a "clean up" of test results it does not help to just delete the test report files from the workspace. Instead corresponding valus have to be removed from the internal build model.
This can be achieved by retrieving the [AbstractTestResultAction](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/junit/hudson/tasks/test/AbstractTestResultAction.html) from the build and set an new (empty) TestResult. Try sth like this:

```
AbstractTestResultAction testResultAction = currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(AbstractTestResultAction.class)
def listener = Jenkins.get().getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME).getBuildByNumber(Integer.parseInt(env.BUILD_NUMBER)).getListener()
testResultAction.setResult(new TestResult(), listener)
```